# How to get all scripts and styles from the header. Including those added by plugins?

Tags: plugins

Good afternoon!

`wp_styles()` or `global $wp_styles` gets styles from the header only of WordPress itself.

And how to get absolutely all styles from the header, including those added by plugins?

I need to get this style added by the WooCommerce plugin:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="jquery-ui-style-css" href="/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css?ver=7.3.0" media="all">
```

But the function `wp_styles()` doesn't see him.

Comment: When are you calling it?

Comment: I need to get this style dynamically to connect on a separate page.
Something like this:`$wp_styles->registered['jquery-ui-style']->src`.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, and I'm not even sure what you mean. What I'm asking is when in the code you are calling `wp_styles()`. If you call it too early scripts and styles from other plugins may not have been registered yet.

Comment: I'm sorry, I really didn't understand your answer...
Following your advice, I tried this:
`add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function() { global $wp_styles; var_dump( $wp_styles ); } );`
...I get a blank screen.

What else can I do?

Comment: Most plugins register their scripts and styles in the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook, so you would need to use it after that. Using `plugins_loaded` wouldn't cause a blank screen unless there was a coding mistake. What's your goal here?

Comment: On a separate page, I plugged in the WordPress functionality using the wp-load.php file.
On this page, I call `var_dump( wp_styles() );` and get an array of styles from WordPress itself, but not plugin styles. Next, I rewrite the code like this: `add_action('plugins_loaded', function() { var_dump( wp_styles() ); } );` - I get a blank screen. Even this code: `add_action('plugins_loaded', function() { var_dump('Hi!' ); } );` also returns a blank screen. Why `add_action` does not work, I do not understand.

Comment: "*I need to get this style added by the WooCommerce plugin*" - why and what do you mean by "get" - get what; the CSS file URL? "*I plugged in the WordPress functionality using the wp-load.php file*" - so you're manually loading WordPress there? Why (what does the page do)? And why did you keep using the `plugins_loaded` hook - Jacob already told you that you should use a hook which runs *after* `wp_enqueue_scripts`, but `plugins_loaded` loads not only before `wp_enqueue_scripts`, but way too early.

Comment: Nothing works that I haven't tried. Even this doesn't work: `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() { echo 'Hi'; }, PHP_INT_MAX );` - an empty screen is output.

Comment: You didn't answer my first 3 questions, so please answer that first. Even better, add your answers to your post, so that everyone can see them clearly.